# PHP and capturing current user from wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a PHP page that I am calling from a WordPress page so that I can run a php INSERT. The problem is, the PHP template will not define the current user id when I call `wp_get_current_user();` below.  I have a form and want to insert what the current user enters to insert into the db for that user's bio. Does this mean I need to pass this variable to this php template from the wordpress page URL link I have to this form? If so, not sure of the formatting/code to do so. But ideally, if this template could somehow get the current user without needing to send it that would be huge!

```
<?php
    //connect
    }
    mysql_select_db("i80_wp1",$con);

    // Get the current user's info 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();


    if(isset($_POST['update'])) { 
        $UpdateQuery = 
            "UPDATE wp_usermeta SET author_bio='".$_POST['author_bio']."'WHERE
            user_id=$current_user and author_bio='".$_POST['hidden']."'";
            mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
```

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. wordpress is enough of a security hole as is, don't make it worse by writing code like this.

Answer (score 0):

to access the wordpress functions in any external php file, copy the below two line of code at the top of your php file.

```
<?php $blogheader = explode("wp-content",$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
include $blogheader[0]."wp-blog-header.php"; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. After doing so, I get this:

Comment: Warning: include(/home/site500/public_html/index.phpwp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/site500/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/page-bio.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/site500/public_html/index.phpwp-blog-header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/site500/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/page-bio.php on line 2

Comment: then you can do as below:
1. get your site url
and include the file wp-blog-header.php which is normally stored in your root folder of your site. in your case it's in 
/home/site500/public_html/wp-blog-header.php.

simply include that file in your php file and things will work.
(Instead of giving a hardcoded path i suggest your to use the $_SERVER variable to find the exact path and append the wp-blog-header.php) Good luck

Comment: Well, getting closer I think. The page displays the form ok, but when I submit the data to insert, I now get: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /home/site500/public_html/page-bio.php on line 9" Line 9 is the mysql_select_db line, but it is connecting fine. The error to me is just saying that it still cannot define the current user logged in in wordpress on this php file template.

Comment: Perhaps I need to do a require_once('XXX.php')? I was reading about this issue. Seems like the function just isn't loading, but if this is the solution, I'm not sure what file I need to require. Something from the php in posts and pages plugin or some wordpress core file perhaps?

Comment: if wp-blog-header.php does not fulfill your need then try including the wp-load.php